# Ubuntu restart without notice

Tags: ubuntu

I am running some research code( Matlab + maybe some CUDA code called from Matlab). The computer runs ubuntu 14.04, latest Matlab and has CUDA 6.0. Whenever I run the code the computer will reboot without a notice. Is there any log file that I can check the reasons?

Answer (score 0):

System-level logging occurs in:

- `/var/log/syslog`
- `/var/log/kern.log`

You can find this by checking the rsyslog configuration at `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`. You can also set up additional log statements here, and then restart rsyslog with `service rsyslog restart`.